# php array_reverse get last in loop

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

So im trying to reverse array and ADD something to last item on loop, when i run this code:

```
$data = ($json['data']);
foreach($data as $item){
    if(isset($item['Metadata']) && $item['Metadata']['id_suscripcion'] == $id_sus){
        if ($item === end($data))
            echo $item['id'].' LAST ELEMENT!';
        }      
    }
```

I get this results:

```
Array
(
    [ticketNumber] => 172252526529700541    
    [Metadata] => Array
        (
            [id_suscripcion] => 0000000000004314
        )

    [id] => 193172252526529772
)

Array
(
    [ticketNumber] => 172242526591400527
    [Metadata] => Array
        (
            [id_suscripcion] => 0000000000004314
        )

    [id] => 193172242526591380
)

Array
(
    [ticketNumber] => 172232526775600149
    [Metadata] => Array
        (
            [id_suscripcion] => 0000000000004314
        )

    [id] => 193172232526775687
)
193172232526775687 LAST ELEMENT!
```

now the problem is when I add array_reverse() `$data = array_reverse($json['data']);` LAST ELEMENT! will not show, any suggestions?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Do you need to loop through the whole array to get the last item or do you just need the last item?

Comment: That's because "LAST ELEMENT!" is not part of the actual array.

Comment: @Ice76 I want to add something to the last item

Comment: @Ered Do you want to add something to every array?

Comment: @Ice76 Exactly...add something to every array and for last a different something

Comment: You only print `LAST ELEMENT` if the last element's `id_subscripcion` matches `$id_sus`. When you reverse the array, you only do that if the first element of the original array matches.

Comment: In your sample data all the `id_subscripcion` are the same. That's probably not true of the real data.

Comment: @Barmar exactly real data changes for id_subscripion that's why I use if isset and if equal

Comment: Do you want to do something to the last item in the array even if it doesn't match `$id_sus`? Then that test should be outside the first `if`. Or are you trying to find the last item that matches the subscription?

Comment: @Barmar I want to do something to last item only if it matches

Comment: Then I can't see any reason why your code wouldn't work. Reversing the array shouldn't have any effect, except now the last item is the original first item. The rest of the code doesn't care how you set `$data`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to add something for every array inside $data and something extra for the last, I suggest you break it up or use a for loop to count.

```
$data = array_reverse($json['data']);
for($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++){
    if( isset( $data[$i]['Metadata'] ) && $data[$i]['Metadata']['id_suscripcion'] == $id_sus){
        if ( $i ===0 || $data[$i] === reset( $data ) )
            echo $item['id'].' LAST ELEMENT!';
        }      
    }
```

Comment: @Barmar exactly real data changes for id_subscripion that's why I use if isset and if equal

Comment: Why do you need reverse array?

Comment: because im using a sql query inside loop and want to save in the order that iI get when I use reverse_array(), but end() stops working, so thats why I need to use reverse array plus get last loop

Comment: it all ends be cause i want to use this command inside loop `id_status='".($item === end($data)? 1:2)` works fine when I don't use reverse_array

Comment: Could you reverse the array, run your action on the first element, and then loop through?

Comment: needs to be inside loop...any chance this could happen?

Comment: Could you try that?

Comment: it shows in first element, i tried changing to end( $data ), same sresult

Comment: @Ered not sure then. If you dont want to break up the loop any more, then I am not sure what else is going on. Maybe it has to do with your `$id_sus` var?

Comment: found solution, used ur initial code and outside the loop i used: `$numItems = count($arr);
$i = 0;
foreach($arr as $key=>$value) {
  if(++$i === $numItems) {
    echo "last index!";
  }
}  `

Comment: @Ered glad that helped and you got it sorted!

Answer (score 0):

I know you said that you want it to be executed in the loop, but you may be better served to have the loop(s) do the work they should do, and after the loops, do your work on the last element:

```
$data = ($json['data']);
foreach($data as $item){
    // Other work for looping...
}

$last = end($data);
$key  = key($data);

if(isset($last['Metadata']) && $last['Metadata']['id_suscripcion'] == $id_sus){
    echo $last['id'].' LAST ELEMENT!';
}
```

This would cut down on the number of tests in the loop.

Another option may be to get the last key prior to looping (to cut down on looped function calls):

```
$data = ($json['data']);

// $data = array_reverse($data);

end($data);
$last_key = key($data);

foreach($data as $key => $item){
    if(isset($item['Metadata']) && $item['Metadata']['id_suscripcion'] == $id_sus){
        if ($key === $last_key)
            echo $item['id'].' LAST ELEMENT!';
    }      
}
```

And finally, for perhaps the real answer, if you are trying to *add* something to the array, you will want to add it to the actual item (what you have there is a copy).  You can do this by using the `$item` as a reference, or by referencing the item by key in the containing array:

```
foreach($data as &$item){
    if(isset($item['Metadata']) && $item['Metadata']['id_suscripcion'] == $id_sus){
        if ($key === $last_key)
            $item[] = 'LAST ELEMENT!';
    }      
}
```

Or:

```
foreach($data as $key => $item){
    if(isset($item['Metadata']) && $item['Metadata']['id_suscripcion'] == $id_sus){
        if ($key === $last_key)
            $data[$key][] = 'LAST ELEMENT!';
    }      
}
```

If you were to go with my first code-block, it would look something like:

```
foreach($data as $item){
    // Other work for looping...
}

end($data);
$key  = key($data);
$last &= $data[$key];

if(isset($last['Metadata']) && $last['Metadata']['id_suscripcion'] == $id_sus){
    $last[] = 'LAST ELEMENT!';
}
```

And one final hint: `isset` and `empty` do not throw errors when referencing variables or array/object members that are not set, so you can (and kind of should) test the whole path before accessing it, for sanity and safety:

```
if (
    isset($last['Metadata']['id_suscripcion']) && 
    $last['Metadata']['id_suscripcion'] == $id_sus
) {
    // do a thing
}
```

EDIT:

If this is still not working when using `array_reverse` it is likely that if this is *coming* from `json`, it may be an object.  Be sure to decode `json` with JS objects as arrays: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: where does array_reverse() fit in all those examples?

Comment: @Ered - Just above the `foreach` loop.  In the event that the `foreach` loop is not included in the example, assume the `foreach` loop occurs above the example.